# Render only particle system?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I've got this particle system of snowflakes inside the volume of a cube:
[image]
But when I render, the cube itself covers up the particles:
[image]
How do I tell Blender to only render the particle system, not the physical cube itself? (Cycles)

Comment: In the particles panel, there is a 'render' section: uncheck 'emitter'

Comment: @lemon I think he just meant to restate your comment in answer form so that I can accept it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the emitter to be rendered, in the particles panel, go to the 'render' section and uncheck 'emitter':

[image]